# How to change selected pane programmatically with animation in PaneManagerView?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to change selected pane programmatically with animation in `PaneManagerView`?

`TitleView` won't change if I call to `model.setCurrentlySelectedIndex(model.nextIndex(), true);`

Tested on real device 9700 bold.